# Animated scroll not working with complete "external" links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I'm building this site julebord.bedriftsdesign.no and implemented animated scroll on this page: http://julebord.bedriftsdesign.no/julebord.html

Now this is the problem. When I use an internal anchor link like (#myanchor) the animated scroll works fine. But if the link is formatted like this http://julebord.bedriftsdesign.no/julebord.html#myanchor It won't work.

I need both to work but am a bit at a loss on how. I'm guessing something has to be changed in the javascript i use right?

Would appreciate any input on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it won't work with your current script because the scroll is triggered by a click not a page load.

You could detect the URL hash on the page load and then manually trigger the click, which would then trigger the scroll.

You could do something like (this isn't tested in your page so it might need some tweaking)

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  $('a[href="#'+window.location.hash.substr(1)+'"]').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm willing to try. One more question before I implement since I'm extremely new to JS. Where in the script do I implement this argument?

Comment: You just need it to run after the document has loaded, so the best place to put it would be inside the jQuery(document).ready() function in your customScript.js file - just underneath your $('a[href^="#"]').on('click') statement, so in between lines 47 & 48